# Request from application on same host causing issue?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I am facing an issue on my spring boot(2.1.7) application( jdk1.8.0_202-i586) . I believe that somehow my application cannot handle properly when the request comes from the other application on the **same host** where my application is deployed. the request from soapUI can be handled as expected.

Below is the error log on my application.

```
14:18:11.858 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-Acceptor] o.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch  : Counting up[https-jsse-nio-8444-Acceptor] latch=1
14:18:11.867 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-1] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel     : The SNI host name extracted for connection [java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/123.456.78.90:8444 remote=/123.456.78.90:34959]] was [null]
14:18:12.211 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : Managed= Tomcat:type=RequestProcessor,worker="https-jsse-nio-8444",name=HttpRequest1
14:18:12.211 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : Looking for descriptor 
14:18:12.211 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : Introspecting 
14:18:12.212 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute virtualHost public java.lang.String org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getVirtualHost() null
14:18:12.212 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute bytesSent public long org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getBytesSent() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setBytesSent(long)
14:18:12.212 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute method public java.lang.String org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getMethod() null
14:18:12.212 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute remoteAddr public java.lang.String org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getRemoteAddr() null
14:18:12.212 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute requestBytesSent public long org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getRequestBytesSent() null
14:18:12.212 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute rpName public javax.management.ObjectName org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getRpName() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setRpName(javax.management.ObjectName)
14:18:12.212 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute contentLength public int org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getContentLength() null
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute workerThreadName public java.lang.String org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getWorkerThreadName() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setWorkerThreadName(java.lang.String)
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute bytesReceived public long org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getBytesReceived() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setBytesReceived(long)
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute requestProcessingTime public long org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getRequestProcessingTime() null
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute globalProcessor public org.apache.coyote.RequestGroupInfo org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getGlobalProcessor() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setGlobalProcessor(org.apache.coyote.RequestGroupInfo)
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute remoteAddrForwarded public java.lang.String org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getRemoteAddrForwarded() null
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute protocol public java.lang.String org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getProtocol() null
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute currentQueryString public java.lang.String org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getCurrentQueryString() null
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute maxRequestUri public java.lang.String org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getMaxRequestUri() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setMaxRequestUri(java.lang.String)
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute serverPort public int org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getServerPort() null
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute requestBytesReceived public long org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getRequestBytesReceived() null
14:18:12.213 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute stage public int org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getStage() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setStage(int)
14:18:12.214 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute requestCount public int org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getRequestCount() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setRequestCount(int)
14:18:12.214 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute maxTime public long org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getMaxTime() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setMaxTime(long)
14:18:12.214 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute processingTime public long org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getProcessingTime() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setProcessingTime(long)
14:18:12.214 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute currentUri public java.lang.String org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getCurrentUri() null
14:18:12.214 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute lastRequestProcessingTime public long org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getLastRequestProcessingTime() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setLastRequestProcessingTime(long)
14:18:12.214 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute errorCount public int org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.getErrorCount() public void org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo.setErrorCount(int)
14:18:12.214 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Setting name: org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo
14:18:12.214 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] o.a.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean   : preRegister org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo@4011bd Tomcat:type=RequestProcessor,worker="https-jsse-nio-8444",name=HttpRequest1
14:18:12.215 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1429e11:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@b87acd:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/123.456.78.90:8444 remote=/123.456.78.90:34959]], Read from buffer: [0]
14:18:12.385 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1429e11:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@b87acd:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/123.456.78.90:8444 remote=/123.456.78.90:34959]], Read direct from socket: [13521]
14:18:12.385 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [POST /Message HTTP/1.1
Host: linux123:8444s
Content-Length: 13394
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/plain

{
  "Header" : null,
  "Body": {
    "msg_Message": {
      "VersionTag": "1",
      "Authentication": {
        "UserLogin": "TestUSer",
        "UserPassword": "cnVsZXM=",
        "UserRealm": "xxx.com"
      },
      "Messages": [
        {
          "Message": {
       ...

       ]
14:18:12.403 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set query string encoding to UTF-8
14:18:12.431 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1429e11:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@b87acd:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/123.456.78.90:8444 remote=/123.456.78.90:34959]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
14:18:12.432 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@910148].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1429e11:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@b87acd:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/123.456.78.90:8444 remote=/123.456.78.90:34959]])

java.lang.Exception: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doClose(NioEndpoint.java:1165) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.close(SocketWrapperBase.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.cancelledKey(NioEndpoint.java:667) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]

14:18:12.432 DEBUG 18928 --- [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] o.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch  : Counting down[https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-4] latch=1
```

Please, advice.

Comment: This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/27734698/10426557

Comment: Jonathan, can you please help me understand why that article helps?  and it seems the issue is not related to the request from same host. I've deployed the client on other host and try from there. the issue is same. I don't get why the request from SoapUI works but not from the other service api. if there is any issue on certification/ssl it should throw the ssl related errors right? i do have logging.level.root=DEBUG to have all logs.